# how to sort string array in ascending order using sort function in C

Tags: c, sorting

Suppose I have a structure named dictionary which contains two char array. I want to sort the dictionary type array 'pair' in ascending order according to the second char array . how to do that using sort function? How do I need to modify the comp?

Comment: C89 defines `qsort()`, you can use that.

Comment: but I want to use sort function.

Comment: `qsort()` _is_ an array sorting function!

Comment: Are you saying `sort()` function from a specific library or have you did implementation of some algorithm itself?

Comment: *"C89 defines qsort(), you can use that"* - *"but I want to use sort function"* - Huh? If `qsort` doesn't classify as a *"sort function"*, then what does?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char message[100];   // string to be sorted
                                  // (totally arbitrary length)
    unsigned char sortOrder[256]; // string containing ASCII chars
                                  // in their sort order
} Pair;

unsigned char rank[256]; // rank of each ASCII character

// qsort() comparison function
int sortByRank(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return ((int)rank[*(signed char *)a] - (int)rank[*(signed char *)b]);
}

// Creates an array by which a character's relative position can be found
// solely from its value.  Characters of rank 0 will appear first when sorted.
// Characters not specified by sortOrder will appear first, since rank is
// global and automatically initialized to zeros.
void initRank(Pair pair)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(pair.sortOrder); i++)
        rank[pair.sortOrder[i]] = i;

    return;
}

int main()
{
    // Create an example pair.  Spaces will be the first characters in the
    // sorted result.
    Pair pair;
    strcpy(pair.message, "this is a test message (123).");
    strcpy(pair.sortOrder, " 321abcdefghijklm.nopqrstuvwxyz()");

    // In this solution, initRank() will need to be called any time the
    // sortOrder is changed.
    initRank(pair); 

    // Sort using the global rank array set by initRank()
    qsort(pair.message, strlen(pair.message), sizeof(char), sortByRank);

    printf("Sorted message: %s\n", pair.message);

    // Output:
    // Sorted message:      321aaeeeghiim.sssssttt()

    return 0;
}
```

Since rank[] is global, this isn't as elegant as might be, but the above solution generally demonstrates how to make use of C's sorting function to do a custom sort based on a second string in a fairly straightforward manner.

Comment: You might make rank[] an int array and define your cmp as simply `return rank[*(char *)a] - rank[*(char*)b];` But +1

Comment: @Anonymous: Thanks, I've simplified the comparison function per your suggestion.

Comment: @Anonymous: I think you mean it's a problem if char defaults to signed; I've went ahead and made char explicitly unsigned everywhere to avoid a possible seg fault if char defaults differently than it had on my system.  (Apologies if you had meant something else.)

Comment: The code is still wrong I think. `unsigned` - `unsigned` is going to be `unsigned`, so your cmp function never returns a negative number. If you change to signed, you still have a problem -- with overflow and underflow (although for ascii it'll work). You need to cast to `int` before doing the subtraction.

Comment: @Anonymous: Thanks, that makes sense.  I glossed over this a bit because test cases worked fine.  Updated answer to cast ranks to ints before doing subtraction.